# emacs ido-mode select and edit completion

Tags: emacs, ido-mode

using ido for find file completion, is it possible to select and edit the first completion? Eg., if I had this, I'd like to complete with apples, but not to ido-exit-minibuffer so I can add to the end of apples:

From:

```
Find file: /home/me/{apples | pears | armadillos | ...}
```

To:

```
Find file: /home/me/apples
```

Cheers,
Tim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>C-e</kbd> (edit input string) seems to do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Rörd, that's what I'm after :)

Answer (score 0):

Just start typing the thing you are looking for and hit `<TAB>` this will attempt to complete the value, if it's not unique ido will list the possible completions, if it is unique then it will complete the selection.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not quite what I'm after, to complete by typing the parts of the completion I'd have to press many keys. My question is is there a key to fill in the input with the first completion as is tab had been pressed as it was the only completion.